# ssh-host-config does not work on latest Windows 10 version

Tags: windows-10, ssh, cygwin

**Steps performed:**

1. Install cygwin via:

   ```bat
   C:\tmp\setup-x86_64.exe -q -B -R C:\cygwin -s http://cygwin.mirror.constant.com -l C:\tmp -A -o -P curl,rsync,dos2unix,make,git,unzip,openssh OpenSSL
   ```
2. ```bat
   mkpasswd -l -c > C:\cygwin\etc\passwd
   mkgroup -l -c > C:\cygwin\etc\groups
   ```

**ssh-host-config:**

- Expected:

  ```bat
  *** Query: Should StrictModes be used? (yes/no) yes
  *** Query: Should privilege separation be used? <yes/no>: yes
  *** Query: New local account 'sshd'? <yes/no>: yes
  *** Query: Do you want to install sshd as a service?
  *** Query: <Say "no" if it is already installed as a service> <yes/no>: yes
  *** Query: Enter the value of CYGWIN for the deamon: [] binmode ntsec
  *** Query: Do you want to use a different name? (yes/no) yes/no
  ```
- Actual:

  ```bat
  *** Query: Should StrictModes be used? (yes/no) yes

  *** Info: Updating /etc/sshd_config file
  *** Info: Sshd service is already installed.
  *** Info: Host configuration finished. Have fun!
  ```

  - Prior to this, in Windows 10 and 7 things worked as expected, but
    not in the latest Windows 10 version since OpenSSL is pre-installed *(uninstalling it doesn't solve the problem)*: `%WinDir%\system32\openssl\sshd.exe`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

step `b` is not anymore needed.

The problem with `ssh-host-config` is that Microsoft installs now as default a `sshd` so you need to use another name as mentioned on latest release

https://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin-announce/2019-04/msg00017.html

```
Portability
-----------

 * sshd(8) Cygwin: Change service name to cygsshd to avoid collision
   with Microsoft's OpenSSH port.
```

Comment: I see that service name is already changes in latest ssh-host-config file

`sshd_config_configured=no`

`port_number=22`

`service_name=cygsshd`

`strictmodes=yes`

Comment: done using `ssh-host-config -N cygsshd`

Comment: Info: Thing like demon name, username and password are not asked while ssh-host-config , but things still work.

Comment: one important thing: permission of .ssh files is very importanat and sensitive, if has to exactly match (giving higher permission like 755, 777) does not work.
* Avoid windows copy paste to move .ssh file.